# Google Drive API Response: but your computer or network may be sending automated queries

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

We are using the PHP SDK of Google spreadsheet API and Google Drive API. We provide customers to use Google Drive/Spreadsheet to backup their data stored on our local server. We use the server-side API.

We recently starting to receive errors from the server-side: 403 ERROR: **We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.**
We are using offline access type, we are not reaching any quotas limits set in the Google API console. Can someone please help us with this issue, please?

Here is

```
$client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__.'/credentials.json');
        $client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
            Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA]);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
        $client->setAccessToken(json_decode($itemID["raw_token"],true));

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$optParams = array(
        'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='XXXXX'",
        'spaces' => 'drive',
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
    );
    $results = $driveService->files->listFiles($optParams);
```

This 403 error sometimes is thrown during the above process.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @leon. I tried calling directly the API and it worked fine for me. Could you maybe explain what verison of the library are you using? Version 2 or 3 for drive? So this error is only happening sometimes? Are you maybe making too many requests?

Comment: Hi @Raserhin , we are using google-api-php-client-2.2.4,  i think it is version 3 for the drive. This error is only started happening recent month and sometimes it can go through. We are not making many requests, far from reaching the quotas.  If it is over the quota, the error should be in JSON 403 return, but this error is weirdly returned as HTML. It is like a return to the end user.

Comment: @Raserhin  I have changed the SDK to google-api-php-client-2.4, still same thing happens.

Comment: Maybe you are not making too many request but you are doing them in very little time? Anyway this seems like it could be a bug so try to post it in [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) to get help there. I don't see a lot of thing that we can do here.